# Is the value of <br> the same between different OSs?

Tags: html, eol, end-of-line

I'm working on code that's reading the content of an HTML page and removes some of the lines from it. To separate different lines I currently use `\n` (LF, which is the default end of line in Linux) but suddenly I remembered that in Windows it's `\r\n` (CRLF in Windows).

In HTML we use `<br>` but because I read the HTML file as text, it is shown as `\n`.

Will it be shown in Windows as `\r\n` (or as the default end of line in other OSs) or will `<br>` always be `\n`?

Comment: What are you using to read it? If you open it in a typical text editor (the sort you'd edit code in), then it'll show as `<br>`, not as a line break of any kind. Otherwise, it depends on the renderer. A browser converts it to a placement rule on where to put the subsequent element, so it's not really meaningful to ask whether, say, FIrefox, uses `\n` or `\r\n` because at that point it's no longer text.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo In my specific case I use pywikibot.Page.text from python, but I mean in general